# VotingApi function takes time to update the database

Tags: database, rating

I have added a menu item that calls a function that calls `votingapi_set_votes` and delete votes. This function works locally fine but when uploaded to the hosting and when i call the function it takes like 5 minutes to update the database with the `votingapi_set_votes` function.

Menu_item's callback calls a function that contains `votingapi_set_votes`.
Locally: i call the menu item with the node id as parameter and the a vote is added to the node.
On Hosting: When i call the menu_item i need to wait five minutes or so to see the node vote updated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code may work for you Try this code in your theme's js file:

```
Drupal.behaviors.Your-Theme-Name = {

 attach: function (context, settings) {

//add your class in click function

    jQuery('.view-id-top_users.view-display-id-page .views-field-php .flag-link-toggle').click(function(){

        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

         location.reload();

        });

    });

  }

    };
```

Comment: I am going to try it vikram, i think it's going to take some time to test as i can't upload any thing for a while. However the solution seems legit. Thanks.